# Ruby on Rails 4: Carrierwave Missing Template error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am a beginner of ruby on rails framework and having issues with gem 'carrierwave'.

【Issue】
I can't post a picture by using carrierwave. When I post a image, the error 'template is missing' pops out on the screen. It works when only a message gets created, which is why I don't understand the gem 'carrierwave'.

Here is my code. I followed many tutorials on the Internet, but none of those worked the way I wanted, I mean posting a picture. Does anyone know how to deal with this issue?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

messages/index.html.haml

```
- if user_signed_in?
  %h1
  = @chat_group.name

  %h4
  = 'Members:'
  - @chat_group.users.each do |user|
    = user.name

  = form_for @message, :url => {:action => :index}, remote: true do |f|
   = f.text_field :body
   = image_tag @message.image.url if @message.image?
   = f.file_field :image
   = f.submit 'send'

  %ul
   = render @messages
```

_messages.html.erb

```
<%= message.body %>  <strong>sent by</strong>  <%= message.user.name %>
<%= message.created_at.strftime("%Y年%m月%d日 %H時%M分") %>
<% if message.image %>
  <%= image_tag message.image.url %>
<% end %>
```

messages_controller.rb

```
def index
  @messages = @chat_group.messages
  @message = Message.new
end

def create
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
  @message.chat_group = @chat_group
  @message.user = current_user

  if @message.save
    flash.now[:notice] = 'successfully sent'
  else
    flash.now[:notice] = 'Unfortunately failed to sent'
  end

  @messages = @chat_group.messages.all
end

private
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:body, :image)
end
```

Message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chat_group
  belongs_to :user

  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 1 }

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

ImageUploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

   def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
   end

end
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#message_body").val("");
$("ul").html("<%=j(render @messages) %>");
$(".layout-notification").append("<%= j(flash.now[:notice]) %>");
```

Comment: can you show your image_uploader.rb ?

Comment: instead `image.url` replace with `image_url`

Comment: @IgorIvancha the replacement did not solve the issue...

Comment: @OmomSun I will add it to my question.

Comment: show, please, your `create.js.erb` file

Comment: you can only post a file along with creating a record in the database. Like you said, it works only when a message is created, it's meant to be that way. You create a record, attach a file to it in the database.

Comment: @IgorIvancha sorry. I will post it.